# How to troubleshoot a VSCode extension not loading after restart?

Tags: visual-studio-code, apollo

I installed and configured the Apollo GraphQL extension in VSCode.  It worked perfectly.

[image: successful console output]

[image: menu]

However, when I close and reopen VSCode it doesn't load. The icon [image: apollo tray icon] never shows up and nothing loads in the console output.

The extension is definitely loaded because syntax highlighting still works but we get none of scheme features.

I tried

- uninstall/reinstall of the extension.
- closing vscode, deleting the extension folder directly, reinstall extension, restart vscode.
- installing the Insiders Edition of vscode and installing the extension there.

In all cases it works the first time but not after a restart.

**How can I troubleshoot/fix this issue?**

Comment: Any updates on this ? I am trying to set up same extension for Local schemas - following documentation but seems like its not working at all for me. Do I need some Webpack configuration to pick apollo.config.js file, or it should run itself?